# W3C validator given warning: No DOCTYPE found! for Kohana 3 Feed Class

Tags: xml, validation, rss, kohana, w3c

I am using the following code of [Feed Class from Kohana 3.0](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Kohana_Feed) to create rss feed.

```
class Controller_Feed extends Controller {

    public function action_best()
    {
        $info = array(
           "title" => "HYIP Monitor,
           "pubDate" => date("D, d M Y H:i:s T"),
           "description" => "Provides the best style of HYIP Rating.",
           "link" => "http://tophyips.info/",
           "copyright" => "TOPHYIPS.INFO",
           "language" => "en-us",
           "ttl" => "5",
        );

        $items = array();   
        $items[1] = array(
           "title" => "Best Rated Hyips Style-1",
           "link" => "http://tophyips.info/monitor/hyip-rating/style-1/best-1",
           "description" => "Best Monitoring Site Style#1",
           "guid" => "http://tophyips.info/monitor/hyip-rating/style-1/best-1",
        );

        $this->response->headers('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
        $this->response->body(Feed::create($info, $items));
    }

}//End File
```

On validation with W3C as you may check on this link: [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftophyips.info%2Ffeed%2F;ss=1;st=1;outline=1;No200=1;verbose=1) given the result stating that document was successfully checked as well-formed XML! but with the following warning:

```
No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

The DOCTYPE Declaration was not recognized or is missing. This probably means that the Formal Public Identifier contains a spelling error, or that the Declaration is not using correct syntax, or that your XML document is not using a DOCTYPE Declaration.
```

Please advise how to solve this warning. What kind of DOCTYPE Declaration I shall use and where to put the code in the file of class Kohana_Feed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3C’s [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) is for (X)HTML, MathML, SVG, and SMIL documents.

For validating feeds, you should use W3C’s [Feed Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

This won’t generate a warning for a missing DOCTYPE, which is not required in XML.

Comment: I have switched the validation to the link. You are correct. It does not generate  the missing DOCTYPE. Thanks a lot.